# How to include a lot of decision making loops for checking a number within a range in a correct way?

Tags: python, list, loops, range, iteration

I am trying to solve a question to generate a list of numbers from a given range by making each number passed through a set of rules to get that number added in the list. Also to find the maximum element from the list.

This is the actual question:
Write a python program which finds the maximum number from num1 to num2 (num2 inclusive) based on the following rules.

1. Always num1 should be less than num2
2. Consider each number from num1 to num2 (num2 inclusive). Populate the number 
   into a list, if the below conditions are satisfied
   a)Sum of the digits of the number is a multiple of 3
   b)Number has only two digits
   c)Number is a multiple of 5
3. Display the maximum element from the list

In case of any invalid data or if the list is empty, display -1.

First of all, I am new to Python and not familiar to solve these type of complex problems. So I think I made a lot of silly mistakes.

```
def find_max(num1, num2):

    max_num=-1
    num_list=[] #list declared
    if(num1<num2): #to check num1 < num2 as said in the question
        for numbers in range(int(num1),int(num2)+1): #for numbers from the range
            tot=0
            count=0
            while(numbers>0): 
                digit=numbers%10
                tot=tot+digit #to generate sum of digits
                numbers=numbers//10 
                count=count+1 #to count the number of digits
                if(tot%3==0 and count==2 and numbers%5==0): 
                    num_list.append(numbers) #to generate the list
                else:
                    print(-1)
    else:
        print(-1)
    max_num = max(num_list) #to find the maximum value in the list
    return max_num

#Provide different values for num1 and num2 and test your program.
max_num=find_max(10,15)
print(max_num)
```

Results I am getting :
-1
-1
-1........

Comment: Homework?  Add some more print statements to find out what test is failing.  something like `print("numbers%5: %d, tot%3: %d, count=%d" % (numbers%5, tot%3,count))`. I would guess that your count is always going to be one.  Also, you can take advantage of string conversion to count digits like `num_digits = len(str(number))`, because a string is just an array of characters, so you can count the array elements.

Comment: @KevinBott _Thanks for your advice. I would surely add more test cases in the future to check parts of the code more easily._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your code is that in your 'while' loop, you're modifying the value which is being checked for the conditions. (lulian has explained this well.)

Actually, your code can be rewritten more simply. You have these requirements. (a) Sum of the digits of the number is a multiple of 3. (b) Number has only two digits (c) Number is a multiple of 5.

**Requirements (a) and (c) can be combined into a single requirement**: if you know middle school mathematics, (a) basically means that the number itself is divisible by 3, and (c) means that it is divisible by 5. Together, they mean that the number should be divisible by 3 times 5, i.e. 15. We can exploit this property.

Let us revisit the problem. Observe that each time invalid data is detected, I use a return statement.

```
def find_max(num1, num2):

    # check for invalid data: 'num1' and 'num2' should be integers
    if type(num1) != int or type(num2) != int:
        return -1

    # check if 'num1' is greater than 'num2'
    if num1 > num2:
        return -1

    # initialize empty list
    num_list = []

    # find the nearest multiple of 15 to 'num1'
    if num1 % 15 == 0:
        nearest_multiple = num1
    else:
        nearest_multiple = num1 + 15 - num1 % 15

    # scan through possible numbers from 'nearest_multiple' to 'num2'
    for numbers in range(nearest_multiple, num2 + 1, 15):
        if 10 <= numbers <= 99 or -99 <= numbers <= -10:
            num_list.append(numbers)

    # if no valid number was detected, the list will remain empty
    if num_list == []:
        return -1

    return max(num_list)
```

Explanation:
First, locate the nearest multiple of 15 greater than or equal to `num1`. So, if `num1` is 15, then `nearest_multiple` is also 15. But if `num1` were 21, then `nearest_multiple` would be 30. (The formula used is pure math.)
Then, we iterate from `nearest_multiple` to `num2` in jumps of 15. That way, we encounter *only* numbers which satisfy *both* (a) and (c). Then we check the number we encounter for condition (b).

Comment: @34.5_So, I see multiple of 15 does the same trick as the 2 conditions stated in the question. Thanks for the answer._

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not working like you want because you are using `numbers` for checking condition, but you're changing it in your code when you are making computations.

```
numbers = numbers // 10
```

So when you'll use it in if block, *numbers* will have a different value not the initial one. 
For example with *numbers = 15* at the start it will become:

> *numbers -> 15 -> 1 -> 0*

Thus when you check `numbers % 5 == 0` it will never pass and the if conditional will fail. Use a copy of the number and every thing will work fine.

#### Revisited code:

```
def function_name(num1,num2):
  num_list=[] #list declared

  if(num1<num2): #to check num1 < num2 as said in the question
      for numbers in range(int(num1),int(num2)+1): #for numbers from the range
        tot=0
        count=0
        copy = numbers
        while(copy>0): 
            digit=copy%10
            tot=tot+digit #to generate sum of digits
            copy = copy//10 
            count = count+1 #to count the number of digits
            if(tot%3==0 and count==2 and numbers%5==0): 
                num_list.append(numbers) #to generate the list
            else:
                print(-1)
  else:
      print(-1)
  if num_list:#if the list is populates with some numbers
    return max(num_list)
  else: return "what you think is needed in case there aren't numbers" #None is a good choice equivalent to null in other programming languages

print(function_name(10,15))
```

#### My idea to implement your function

Not the best, but its shorter and more readable.

```
def function_name(num1,num2):
  num_list=[] #list declared

  if(num1<num2): #to check num1 < num2 as said in the question
      for number in range(int(num1),int(num2)+1): #for numbers from the range

        # for every char return its int and group all in a list
        # [int(digit) for digit in str(number)]
        tot = sum( [int(digit) for digit in str(number)])

        #count how many char are that is like saying how many digits
        count= len(str(number)) 

        if(tot%3==0 and count==2 and number%5==0): 
            num_list.append(number) #to generate the list
        else:
            print(-1)
  else:
      print(-1)
  if num_list:#if the list is populates with some numbers
    return max(num_list)
  else: 
    return "what you think is needed in case there aren't numbers" #None is a good choice equivalent to null in other programming languages

print("Max", function_name(10,15))
```

Comment: _Thank you very much @lulian_. I was not knowledgeable that when number was declared, it's value would change from that of the initial one. Got something new to learn today.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_max(num1, num2):
if (num1<num2):


    max_num=-1
    for i in range(num1,num2 + 1,1):
        if (10 <= i <= 99 or -99 <= i <= -10):
            j = i/10
            k= i%10
            if ((j+k)%3==0 and i%5 == 0):
                max_num = i
# Write your logic here
    return max_num
else:
    return -1
```

#Provide different values for num1 and num2 and test your program.
max_num=find_max(-100,500)
print(max_num)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

```
def find_max(num1, num2):

max_num=-1
num_list=[] 
if(num1<num2): 
    for numbers in range(int(num1),int(num2)+1): 
        tot=0
        count=0
        while(numbers>0): 
            digit=numbers%10
            tot=tot+digit 
            numbers=numbers//10 
            count=count+1
            if(tot%3==0 and count==2 and numbers%5==0): 
                num_list.append(numbers) 
            else:
                print(-1)
else:
    print(-1)
max_num = max(num_list) 
    return max_num

max_num=find_max(10,15)
print(max_num)
```

Comment: Looks like Iulian's answer. Please explain how (and why) it differs from the former.